# Rstudio shiny renderdatatable change font to monospace?

Tags: datatables, shiny

In Rstudio shiny renderDataTable, how can I change the font to monospace?
Is this an option in shiny itself or do I need to change it after calling renderDataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. I made it work with this line:

```
     ,div(dataTableOutput("mytable"), style = "font-family: Courier,courier; font-size:70%",conditionalPanel("$('#mytable').hasClass('recalculating')",tags$div('Loading ... ')))
```